# StreamReader está a ler uma linha que não existe?

Tags: c#

Eu quero ler um ficheiro CSV e guardá-lo em uma tabela, mas por alguma razão continua a dar o seguinte erro:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
>
> line was null.

Eu já corri o debug e reparei que ele está a ler uma linha que não existe, por exemplo, chega a linha 194 com x valores (supostamente a ultima linha do ficheiro e depois lê mais uma linha (195) que não existe e não tem qualquer tipo de valores (null). Tentei dar fix nisto através abrindo o ficheiro CSV com o Notepad e verifiquei que existia um linha a mais sem nada e apaguei e guardei e após isto devia funcionar e não está.

Aqui está o meu código:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new streamReader(@"PATH"))
{
   var datatable = new DataTable();
   datatable.Columns.Add("PowerPlantId", typeof(string));
   datatable.Columns.Add("AssetId", typeof(int));
   string line;

   line = sr.ReadLine();
   if (line != null)
   {
      do
      {
         line = sr.ReadLine();
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(line + "\n");
         string[] lineitems = line.Split(",");
         DataRow dr = datatable.NewRow();
         dr["PowerPlantId"] = lineitems[0];
         dr["AssetId"] = lineitems[1];
         datatable.Rows.Add(dr);
      } while (line != null);
   }
```

Comment: Já editei, obg.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O que está acontecendo é que você está tentando fazer todas as operações na linha para depois checar se ela é nula, o que não faz muito sentido.

Isso deve funcionar:

```
string line;

while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) //Lê a linha e já checa se ela é nula
{
    // demais operações
}
```

Comment: So agora tive tempo para vir cá testei o que disse mas agora deu outro erro relacionado com o array so não percebi pq?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ki96yn

Comment: Você está lendo a linha 2 vezes. Retire a linha 46 q deve funcionar. @Jonas

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ki9feu  -- experimentei mas sem sucesso, não tou a perceber o pq de ele dar este erro supostamente parece estar tudo bem.

Comment: Essa excessão indica que você está tentando acessar uma posição do array que não existe. Basicamente é porque você está dando `Split` na linha e tentando acessar o segundo valor, mas ela só tem 1.

Comment: ja vi o que era, o split devia ser ; em vez de , e assim ele ja ta ler os valores bem, mas ainda assim tenho 1 erro http://prntscr.com/kibwdx.

Comment: O assetid são valores inteiros mas ele tá a ler o header que é string e acho que está entrar em conflito por isso, existe alguma maneira de por isto melhor?

Comment: @Jonas A sua pergunta original já foi respondida. Caso a resposta tenha te ajudado, marque-a como correta. Caso tenha outras dúvidas crie outra pergunta.